# Removing dots from url in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Anybody can help and show me how to remove dots from url (without the last dot of the ".html") in .htaccess

The reason that I have more than 3000 listings ending with " L.L.C. " and after upgrading phpmydirectory I removed all the dots from listing friendly urls,

Now there are 3000 404 error in Google and my listings ranking is down,

For example , in my system:

```
www.mydomain.com/company-name-llc.html
```

and in Google:

```
www.mydomain.com/company-name-l.l.c..html
```

I just need away to redirect the url witout dots or remove the dots from url and also witout loosing the last dot of `.html`

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?(\.html|php$) $1$2$3$4 [NC]
```

But it was making a 404 error on all pages in my site.

Please if anybody can help herel, so everybody can get benefit in the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this rule probably isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?\.?([^.]*)?(\.html|php$) $1$2$3$4 [NC]
```

is that you have 6 capture groups, but only backreference 4 of them.

A simpler rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.([^/]*)\.html$ /$1$2.html [L,R=301]
```

This will loop until there are no more stray dots.

Comment: Working like a charm, thank a lot, you saved my life time, really you are the man ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and put this line in your `htaccess` located in Root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.\.html$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: add your htaccess file to your question